# Call function in .vimrc from abbreviation in .vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim

Tags: vim

I have a VIM function in `.vimrc` that is called by a few abbreviations. I would like to move those abbreviations to PHP-specific, C-specific, and a few other file-type specific files, but they no longer see the functions in `.vimrc` as in scope. How can I increase the scope of functions in `.vimrc`?

**EDIT:**
I've tried this:

```
 - bruno:~$ cat .vimrc
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
function! Hello()
   return "hello"
endfunction

 - bruno:~$ cat .vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim
abbr xyz <C-R>=Hello<CR>
```

However, I only get `E121: Undefined variable: Hello` when typing "xyz" in a .php file. I added the prefix `g:` to both the function declaration and to the function call, but that did not help either. Nor did it help to add the prefix only to the function declaration. This is on VIM 7.3, Kubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Did you abuse `s:` by any chance?

Comment: Thanks Romainl, in fact I did not abuse an `s:`! I did try with and without `g:` prefixes but that did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't give an example of a function and an abbreviation that don't work, so it's impossible to tell what you did wrong. Here is an example of a function in my ~/.vimrc,

```
function! Hello()
   return "hello"
endfunction
```

and an abbreviation in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim,

```
abbr xyz <C-R>=Hello()<CR>
```

that work as expected. Open a new php file,

```
$ vim foo.php
```

type

```
This is a test of xyx
```

and upon hitting the space bar, that becomes

```
This is a test of hello
```

Comment: Thank you. I have started with a blank .vimrc and ftplugin file, and added your text and only `set nocompatible` and `filetype plugin on` to .vimrc. When opening `somefile.php` and typing the text `xyz`, I get the message `E121: Undefined variable: Hello`. This is VIM 7.3 on Kubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I see the problem. I'm sorry, my fault. I mistyped the abbreviation and omitted the parentheses from the function call. "Hello<CR>" should have been "Hello()<CR>". I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Actually, I had a whole mess of problems but I was able to use your working example and work backwards, Googling the error messages as I went. I actually started this quest two hours ago, seconds after you posted a working example! Thank you very, very much!